# Uses of vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: vector-spaces, big-list, rational-numbers, applications

I know of two applications of vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$ to problems posed by people not specifically interested in vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$:

- Hilbert's third problem; and
- The Buckingham pi theorem.

What others are there?

Comment: Basically all of classical algebraic number theory, for starters, which was developed to answer questions about the good ol' integers.

Answer (score 4):

One nice application is proving the following theorem:

> A rectangle
>   R
>   with side lengths
>   $1$
>   and
>   $x$
>   , where
>   $x$
>   is irrational, cannot be “tiled” by finitely many squares (so that the squares
>   have disjoint interiors and cover all of
>   R
>   ).

The proof can be found here: http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/stml-53-matousek-1.pdf, as Miniature 12 (pg. 39).

Comment: Indeed, this is a very nice problem where the use of a Hamel basis is actually natural. However, I should note that one does **not** require a full Hamel basis, if one is careful to only take the span of the relevant reals.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $\mathsf{CH}$, one can show that $\Bbb R$ is the union of countably many metrically rigid subsets by viewing it as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$. (A set $D$ in a metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$ is *metrically rigid* if no two distinct two-point subsets of $D$ are isometric.) This is mentioned in Brian M. Scott and Ralph Jones, *Metric rigidity in* $E^n$, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. $53$, $1975$, $219{-}222$, though the paper itself contains a different proof of a more general result.