# Applications of linear algebra other than Euclidean vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, soft-question, applications, motivation

A typical example of finite-dimensional vector space is Euclidean space  $\mathbb{R}^n$, but there are other type of it. For example, the space of polynomials whose order is less than $n$, the space of solutions of a linear differential equation, etc...

Are there interesting application of linear algebra to a space other than $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Markov chains...of the top of my head.

Comment: $F_2^n$ (vector spaces over finite fields) for coding theory, or for applications in graph theory and algorithms. The space of complex valued function on the vertices of a graph is another important one, especially for spectral graph theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_graph_theory. (On a more advanced level, there are homology/cohomology vector spaces.)

Comment: linear error-correcting codes?

Comment: A bit related question on MathOverflow: [Elementary applications of linear algebra over finite fields](https://mathoverflow.net/q/118903). Some related questions on this site: [Uses of vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1550923), [Real life applications of general vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177153), [How does linear algebra help with computer science?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/344879), [Applications of real numbers being a vector space over the rational numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3472273).